# Bluetooth audio streaming over a2dp vs sockets

Tags: android, sockets, audio, bluetooth

I'm using bluetooth to transfer data and audio from phone to windows computer. At the moment i have 2 socket (rfcomm) connections, 1 for data and second one for pure audio packets.

Could someone explain what advantages i could get, if i implement a2dp properly for audio transfer instead of over pure socket transfer.